# How to get a tabular summary from srspair alignment file?

Tags: sequence-alignment

I checked EMBOSS but there is no tabular output for pairwise alignment. 
I can write a script but would like to know if there is already a tool to summarize an alignment in [srspair](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/docs/themes/AlignFormats.html) format in the form of a table (`merger` from the EMBOSS collection gives a tabular summary of the differences but `needle` doesn't).